# Комбинированные операции Java

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, всегда ли операция `a+=s;` эквивалентна `a=a+s;` Нет ли исключений?

Answer (score 2):

- Из [cпецификации **`[15.26.2]`:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

- Соответственно, если типы операндов разные (например, `short` и `int`), то выражение `a = a + b` не всегда эквивалетно `a += b,` поскольку во втором случае **будет происходить неявное преобразование.**